# output category with child categories and posts and pagination

Tags: laravel, eloquent, paginator

I want to get category with all children subcategories and posts where id = category_id.
Posts should be paginated.
In category model I have 2 relations.

```
    public function children()    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function posts() { 
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'category_id'); 
    }
```

In controller I have this function

```
    public function getCategoryWithPaginatedPosts($slug, $perPage = null)
    {
        $columns = ['id', 'parent_id', 'title', 'slug', 'description', 'image'];
        $postsColumns = ['category_id','title','text'];

        $result = Category::whereSlug($slug)
            ->select($columns)
            ->with('children')
            ->with(['items' => function ($q) use ($postColumns) { 
                $q->wherePublished(true)
                  ->select($postColumns)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
                  ->paginate(); 
            }]) 
            ->first();
     }
```

Pagination doesn't work.
I just see that number of items is equal to $perPage parameter (and I have more items), but I don't see paginator inside **dd($result->items)**

It works like that, though I believe it is not the best way to do that.
So I can do it in few steps.
In first step I retrieve all data from DB and convert models to array, because I don't need models on webpage and I suppose it works faster like that. I would use **->toBase()** if it could take mutators and relations from the model.
Second step I convert array into stdClass, because it is more comfortable in blade to work with object rather than with array.
Third step is to paginate items with **mypaginate** function (manual paginator in AppService Provider).

```
    public function getCategoryWithPaginatedPosts($slug, $perPage = null)
    {
        $columns = ['id', 'parent_id', 'title', 'slug', 'description', 'image'];
        $postsColumns = ['category_id','title','text'];

        $result = Category::whereSlug($slug)
            ->select($columns)
            ->with('children')
            ->with(['items' => function ($q) use ($postColumns) { 
                $q->wherePublished(true)
                  ->select($postColumns)
                  ->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
            }]) 
            ->first()
            ->toArray();

        $result = Arr::arrayToObject($result);
        $result->items = collect($result->items)->mypaginate($perPage);

        return $result;

     }
```

Comment: why are you applying `first` after the pagination query results ?

Comment: **first** is applied to Category, not to Items. Look in question again. I changed code a little bit, but still not working

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `->first()` after  `->paginate()`, change something like this,

```
 $result = Category::whereSlug($slug)
        ->select($columns)
        ->with('children')
        ->with(['items' => function ($q) use ($postColumns) { 
            $q->wherePublished(true)
              ->select($postColumns)
              ->orderBy('id', 'ASC')
        }]) 
       ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: In your code paginate applied to Category, not to Items. And I checked that - it doesnt work. What it does is just wrap one category into paginator. And items still not paginated.

Comment: Please try do one thing, remove  ->select($postColumns), and try again

Comment: It doesnt help. Why do you think it could help?

Comment: I have one solution how to make pagination work on items (manually), but it is not very beautiful and therefore I cannot accept it myself as answer.

Comment: If you have a solution, please share it with us.

Comment: added in the topic